# Is it possible to disable chart located in charts folder in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a subchart in `charts/` directory. I would like to disable it for some deployments.

Is it possible somehow? Currently i see the only way to add condition to all templates like below:

deployment.yaml

```
{{- if .Values.isDev }}
deployment code
{{- end }}
```

service.yaml

```
{{- if .Values.isDev }}
service code
{{- end }}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb I always have

```
{{- if .Values.enabled }}
...
{{- end }}
```

in every file in every subchart. Depending on situation the default value will be either `true` for regular components or `false` for dev related, or simply `false` for everything if I want to enable these in completely selective manner. A typical values for deployment for this approach looks like ie.:

```
api:
  enabled: true
  database:
    host: mysql-dev

mysql:
  enabled: false

mysql-dev:
  enabled: true
```

Answer (score 18):

Also, for current version of Helm (2.12 at this time), it is also possible to write a `requirements.yaml` in which one can specify not only remote charts for Helm to download, but also Charts inside the `charts` folder. In this `requirements.yaml` one can specify a `condition` field for each dependency. This field is the path for a parent's Value.

So, for instance, given this `requirements.yaml`:

```
dependencies:
  - name: one-dep
    version: 0.1.0
    condition: one-dep.enabled
  - name: another-dep
    version: 0.1.0
    condition: another-dep.enabled
```

Your `values.yaml` could have:

```
one-dep:
  enabled: true

another-dep:
  enabled: false
```

This will result in Helm only including `one-dep` chart.
It's worth noting that if the path specified in the `condition` does not exist, it defaults to `true`.

[Here's the link to the doc](https://docs.helm.sh/developing_charts/#tags-and-condition-fields-in-requirements-yaml)

Comment: Beware though, if your `requirements.yaml` also refers to remote charts, the lack of field `repository` on your local-dependency entries will cause you problems when executing `helm dependency update`, see [this issue](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3742). Work-around [here](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3742#issuecomment-383095917).

Comment: Anyhow this comment is IMHO way less invasive than the accepted answer. So if you use a current version I recommend this

Comment: Totally agree, I am glad to have read more comments. Don't do the approved answer, it's just not good.

Answer (score 7):

Before Helm 3 there was no possibility to disable in **requirements.yaml** "local" unpacked charts, repository field was always required, thus there was no possibility to disable unpacked charts all along. This is also mentioned in this comment [Is it possible to disable chart located in charts folder in kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47654486/is-it-possible-to-disable-chart-located-in-charts-folder-in-kubernetes/62173163#comment102749558_53876683)

In Helm 3 this issue is solved, thanks to https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3742#issuecomment-574056164
My Chart.yaml looks like this:

```
dependencies:
  - name: mongodb-replicaset
    version: ^3.15.1
    repository: https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com
    condition: mongodb.enabled
  - name: elasticmq
    version: 0.1.0
    condition: elasticmq.enabled
  - name: jhipster-registry
    version: 0.1.0
    condition: jhipster-registry.enabled
```

My helm version is 3.2.1
Now it just displays warning like this, but condition works anyway:

```
Update Complete. ⎈Happy Helming!⎈
Saving 3 charts
Downloading mongodb-replicaset from repo https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com
Dependency elasticmq did not declare a repository. Assuming it exists in the charts directory
Dependency jhipster-registry did not declare a repository. Assuming it exists in the charts directory
Deleting outdated charts
```

So built-in chart disabling doesn't break anything anymore and can be used.